# Can't close in-browser ad pop-up using Selenium and is killing my automation

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape information from this website [Singapore Streetdirectory](https://www.streetdirectory.com/), it's sort of like a Google Map but localized to only Singapore. So what I need to do is to key in a postal code to the search bar, click on search and scrape the street address. I have more than a thousand postal code to process.

The annoying thing is that when I launch this webpage, there will always be an in-browser ad popup. I tried to close it with Selenium using the following code and it doesn't work:

```
close_ad = driver.find_element_by_id('btn_close')
close_ad.click()
```

I wanted to close by using xpath and look for their 'href' but the href appears to be some java code and it also doesn't seems to work.

I like to ask if there is any solutions on this or workaround? The ultimate plan is to run this codes in headless browser mode. Below is my full code for your reference if necessary

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Applications/chromedriver') # , options=options

driver.get('https://www.streetdirectory.com/')
driver.set_window_position(0,23)
print(driver.title)

time.sleep(3)

close_ad = driver.find_element_by_id('a.btn_close')
close_ad.click()
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: driver.getWindowHandle() will return the driver's current window handle.  driver.getWindowHandles() will return all the browser's handles (UID the browser uses for the windows/tabs).  Comparing all handles versus the driver's will tell you which handle is the popup.  You can then switch the driver using driver.switchTo().window(handle) to that window handle and close it... then switch the driver back to the original handle.  ExpectedCondition of "numberOfWindowsToBe" helps here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use headless also with following

driver.get("https://www.streetdirectory.com/")
html_content = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
print(html_content)

Comment: I need to first search for a postal code before I scrape.